# How to call a method of RecyclerView adapter in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment with a `recyclerview`. Here, I'm using a custom method to update the adapter with new `dataset`.

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter .ViewHolder>{
              .....
     public void addNewDataset(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
         ......
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I have called the method like the following, in my Fragment.

```
myRecyclerAdapter.addNewDataset(data);
```

Please help me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: myRecyclerAdapter.addNewDataset(index) is called or not??

Comment: Compiler showing "cannot resolve method myRecyclerApater.addNewDataSet()" error message

Comment: seems like you are trying to pass `index`(which indicates an `int`) but `addNewDataset` is expecting an `ArrayList` of `<Integer>` type  so create  an appropriate method with required parameter type plus always add complete details we don't know what is `index` etc

Comment: @PavneetSingh comment is correct..change like that

Comment: addNewDataset(data); data is arraylist??

Comment: yes, the data is arraylist

Comment: @Kashyap Add more code of adapter and fragment so we can easily identify your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to cast recyclerView adpter than call method like this

```
((MyRecyclerAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).addNewDataset(data);
```

Compiler search addNewDataset() method in default adapter

Answer (score 0):

**Make public method in adapter.**

```
 public void addNewDataset(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
         ......
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Now make object of adapter in fragment like:**

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(); //make object of adpater like this
adapter.addNewDartaset(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling this addnewDataset please check data object reference is not having null value.

```
if(data!=null){
     myRecyclerAdapter.addNewDataset(data);    
}

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter .ViewHolder>{
     private ArrayList<Integer> mData;
              .....
     public void addNewDataset(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
      if(mData==null){
         mData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }
      //If in case you are passing all new array list of integers
      mData = data;
      //If you want to add new one data to existing array list
      mData.addAll(data);

      //Use one condition of code from above on the basis of your requirement.
         ......
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler is not identifying the  myRecyclerAdapter.addNewDataset(data);

Comment: addNewDataset(data)

Comment: Then add more code for adapter how you are initializing it and another setup for RecyclerView related to LayoutManager?